# kafka __consumer_offsets segment file not deleted after expiration time

Tags: apache-kafka

As mentioned in the title, the segment file is not deleted for a long time, which makes the partition size very large(larger than 100G).

In my opinion, __consumer_offsets cleanup policy is compact, and those messages inactive should be deleted after the expiration time. The value default is 1 day, which is hard code.

```
  val OffsetsRetentionMinutes: Int = 24 * 60  //KafkaConfig.scala

  offsetsRetentionMs = config.offsetsRetentionMinutes * 60 * 1000L //GroupCoordinator.scala
```

From the image below, however, I consume the message from __consume_offsets, the expire time is far beyond 1 day, it is still not deleted.
[image]

[image]

Enviroment:

- kafka 0.9.0.1
- jdk 1.7.0_80

Answer (score 1):

Check `log.segment.bytes`. By default it is `1G` and segment is closed after it reaches to that size. Retention policies are not applied to segments which are not closed.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I checked the __consumer_offsets config policy, which is segment.bytes=104857600,cleanup.policy=compact. While each segment file is 100M exactly.  Indeed, using lsof  found those segments are not closed, very wired..